# Query dbpedia asking for birthplace of two categories in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am trying to get a list of:

Person A, BirthPlace of A, Person B, BirthPlace of B

where the birthplace is a city.

The relationship between person A and person B is that person A "influenced" person B. My code so far is as follows:

```
SELECT ?person ?birthplace ?influenced ?birthplace2
WHERE {
?person a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
?person dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace .
?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?person dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace2 .
?influenced a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
?country rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Country .
FILTER (str(?birthplace2) = str(?country))
FILTER (str(?birthplace) = str(?country))
}
```

At the moment I am doing country because that is only thing which works.

Currently, this is just giving me two columns with the *same* birthplace. It isn't showing the influenced person's birthplace.

Ideally I want the latitude and longitude of each birth city as well, such as:

Person A, BirthPlace of A, Lat, Long, Person B, BirthPlace of B, Lat, Long

But this might be too much to ask. Sorry, I'm new to SPARQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query you have:

```
?person dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace .
?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?person dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace2 .
```

which says that `?person` was born in both `?birthplace` and `?birthplace2`. I think you meant:

```
?person dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace .
?person <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/influenced> ?influenced.
?influenced dbpedia2:placeOfBirth ?birthplace2 .
```

As for getting the lat and long of each city, right now dbpedia is down so I can't look at the city resources to see how they map to geo-coordinates. However, once dbpedia is back up, you can do a SPARQL describe query:

```
describe <http://dbpedia.org/... rest of resource URI>
```

and see what you get back. That will tell you which predicates you need to use to pull out the location. Beware that if the lat/long information is missing, you won't see that city in the results unless you put the part of the query pattern that selects out the location in a SPARQL `optional` clause.

**Update**

OK, DbPedia is back up now. I believe this is what you want:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2 
                ?lat1 ?long1 ?lat2 ?long2
WHERE 
{
  ?person1 a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
           dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace1 ;
           dbpedia-owl:influenced ?person2 .
  ?person2 dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace2 .

  optional {
    ?birthplace1 geo:lat ?lat1 .
    ?birthplace1 geo:long ?long1 .

    ?birthplace2 geo:lat ?lat2 .
    ?birthplace2 geo:long ?long2 .
  }
}
```

**Update 2**

The query works for me in [dbpedia/iSparql](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/) (here's a [perma-link](http://dbpedia.org/isparql/view/?query=PREFIX%20geo:%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#%3E%0APREFIX%20dbpedia-owl:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0APREFIX%20dbpedia:%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20?person1%20?birthplace1%20?person2%20?birthplace2%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?lat1%20?long1%20?lat2%20?long2%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20?person1%20a%20dbpedia-owl:Person%20;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%20?birthplace1%20;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl:influenced%20?person2%20.%0A%20%20?person2%20dbpedia-owl:birthPlace%20?birthplace2%20.%0A%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20?birthplace1%20geo:lat%20?lat1%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?birthplace1%20geo:long%20?long1%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%20?birthplace2%20geo:lat%20?lat2%20.%0A%20%20%20%20?birthplace2%20geo:long%20?long2%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&endpoint=/sparql&maxrows=50&timeout=&default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&view=1&amode=0)):

[image: iSparql results]

**Update 3**

Restricting to only cities:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?person1 ?birthplace1 ?person2 ?birthplace2 
                ?lat1 ?long1 ?lat2 ?long2
WHERE 
{
  ?person1 a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
           dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace1 ;
           dbpedia-owl:influenced ?person2 .
  ?person2 dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?birthplace2 .

  ?birthplace1 a dbpedia-owl:City .
  ?birthplace2 a dbpedia-owl:City .

  optional {
    ?birthplace1 geo:lat ?lat1 .
    ?birthplace1 geo:long ?long1 .

    ?birthplace2 geo:lat ?lat2 .
    ?birthplace2 geo:long ?long2 .
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can just get a list of cities and feed that into google maps to pull out latitudes and longitudes I think. This would probably get a more complete list.

Comment: I tried that in http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ but it didn't work. Where do you find if the respective requests are available?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work in snorql. It does work in iSparql - see update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that it is giving the city and the country. I just wanted a unique city for each person. It should just be a unique person with a unique influence. perhaps limiting it to cities only would help.

Comment: At some point, you should take over updating your query for yourself! I have updated the query to restrict the answers to only cities, see the query in the answer. There are still multiple rows in the results, because of variants in the lat/long. This is an issue with the source data, not the spaqrl query. I think your original question is answered; if you agree please accept this answer by clicking on the tick mark. If you have additional questions, such as how to deal with multiple values for lat/long, please start a new question topic.

Comment: Thanks for being one of the few people on the internet to explain this succinctly.